# Remove counter from Facebook Likes button

Tags: wordpress, facebook, button

I've got this Facebook Like button on my Wordpress website. But it has a counter that says something like "Be the first of your friends to like this". I'd like to remove that text but I've no idea how.

Here's the code I inserted where I want the buttons to appear.

```
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : '1853814878180659',
      xfbml      : true,
      version    : 'v2.7'
    });
  };

  (function(d, s, id){
     var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
     fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
   }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>

<div
  class="fb-like"
  data-share="true"
  data-width="450"
  data-show-faces="true">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using the **standard** layout for your Facebook button (it is the default value for the **data-layout** attribute) - please use the **button** layout:

```
<div
  class="fb-like"
  data-share="true"
  data-layout="button" 
  data-width="450"
  data-show-faces="true">
</div>
```